# How can I remove small pixel clusters from a transparent png using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, filter

I am trying to remove random pixel clusters noise from a transparent png using python.

[image]

I have used eroding and then dilating like this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test1.png')
blurred_img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 1)

kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(blurred_img, kernel, iterations=1)
output = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel, iterations=1)

cv2.imwrite('output.png', output)
```

but this blurs the image to the point where it loses a lot of details:

[image: Blured image]

I have tried many alternatives but I just can't obtain the result I want... The original image just without that random pixel noise around it. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You might try converting to gray and threshold. Then get contours and filter contours on area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

area_opening from [skimage](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.area_opening) can be used on the alpha channel. We use the cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED flag to get this channel and modify it.

the following code has an output

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import area_opening

img = cv2.imread('test.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img[:,:,3][area_opening(img[:,:,3], 7) == 0] = 0
cv2.imwrite('output.png', img)
```

[image: image with dots removed]

Comment: It seems like this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!